# Как правильно пишется слово «FLASH УЧЕБНИК»?

Tags: грамматика

Как правильно пишется слово «FLASH УЧЕБНИК»?

Answer (score 2):

Пишется через дефис, как и все сложные слова с иноязычными приставками.

Answer (score 1):

Флеш-учебник.